# ¿Cuáles son las abreviaturas para los meses?

Tags: abreviaturas, tiempo

He visto muchas abreviaturas para los meses en español. Son muy diferentes y estoy confundida. ¿Ustedes me pueden confirmar si son las siguientes?

```
febrero    > feb.  
abril      > abr.  
mayo       > may.  
junio      > jun.  
agosto     > ago.  
septiembre > sep.  
octubre    > oct.  
noviembre  > nov.  
diciembre  > dic.
```

Las abreviaturas que puse van con minúsculas y puntos y son para los meses que necesito.

Creo que ninguna de las listas que he visto lleva todas esas abreviaturas juntas, yo las recogí de más de una lista. Es que mi colección me parece más lógica, porque todas tienen tres letras. ¿Se puede hacer eso o hay que seguir una sola lista para un texto?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Por una vez, y sin que sirva de precedente, un poco de código fuente puede ayudar a resolver esta pregunta (C# en este caso):

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
{
    var date = new DateTime(2017, i, 1);
    Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("MMM"));
}
```

Este código nos da la siguiente lista de nombres de meses abreviados para el español:

```
ene.
feb.
mar.
abr.
may.
jun.
jul.
ago.
sep.
oct.
nov.
dic.
```

Resulta curioso el caso de "may.", ya que incumple la norma de la RAE [comentada por fedorqui](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/19926/12637), que dice que una abreviatura debe omitir al menos dos letras para tener sentido. Por no hablar de que dos acaban en vocal, lo que tampoco se aconseja.

Comment: El _locale_ de UNIX me devuelve la misma lista pero sin el punto final: `for i in {1..12}; do LC_ALL=es_ES.utf8 date "+%b" -d"$i/1/2017"; done` ¡+1 por la idea de mirarlo así!

Comment: Creo que hay que distinguir entre abreviatura y símbolo. En este caso, lo que se muestra es el símbolo de 3 letras para representar el mes.

Comment: @gparis Los símbolos no se escriben con punto final, mientras que el código fuente escrito muestra los nombres de los meses con un punto, lo que los convierte en abreviaturas. ¿Los meses del año tienen símbolos en español?

Comment: Yo no entiendo nada de eso de los códigos, pero me gustan las abreviaturas como escribió, Carlos, a pesar de mi ignorancia en este tema. (Son como las que puse.) Pero lo de mayo fue una de las cosas que me confundieron. Bueno. Muchas gracias. :)

Answer (score 6):

Fundéu tiene una explicación larga e interesante que detallo a continuación. Sin embargo, sus sugerencias suenen poco comunes, por lo que [me han emplazado](https://twitter.com/i/redirect?url=https%3A%2F%2Ftwitter.com%2FFundeu%2Fstatus%2F836963144627073024%3Fcn%3DcmVwbHk%253D%26refsrc%3Demail&t=1&cn=cmVwbHk%3D&sig=5fe9fdf17d111f0a1b3c41809f09ff5882adbfbf&iid=bd167a504b594ef087df8bc76a906a70&uid=332572000&nid=27%201489) a esta tabla extraída de Wikilengua en su artículo [*Abreviaciones en fechas*](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Abreviaciones_en_fechas):

> [image]
>   <sub>copio de momento como imagen, a la espera de editarlo en formato markdown mínimamente leíble</sub>

Seguramente la opción natural es usar el *código trilítero* (la más común), si bien si pides explícitamente *abreviatura* deberías tomar los valores de la segunda columna.

La explicación de Fundéu en [*meses (abreviaturas y símbolos)*](http://www.fundeu.es/consulta/meses-abreviaturas-y-simbolos-2386/) detalla:

> Las abreviaturas de los meses tal como aparecían en las obras Académicas de hace algunos años, son las siguientes (omitimos algunas sin uso en la actualidad):
>
> ```
> en.
> febr.
> mzo.
> abr.
> my.
> jun.
> jul.
> ag. (o agto.)
> sept. (o set. o setbre.)
> oct. (u octbre.)
> nov. (o novbre.)
> dic. (o dicbre.)
> ```

Luego sigue diciendo:

> En calendarios, cuadros, gráficos y ciertas aplicaciones informáticas es frecuente el uso de códigos o símbolos de una, dos o tres letras. Los de una letra son:
>
> E / F / M / A / M / J / J / A / S / O / N / D.
>
> Los de tres letras son:
>
> ENE / FEB/ MAR / ABR / MAY / JUN / JUL / AGO / SET (o SEP) / OCT / NOV / DIC.
>
> Los de dos letras no tienen una forma asentada, pero dos sistemas habituales son:
>
> EN / FE / MA / AB / MY / JN / JL / AG / SE / OC / NO / DI.
>
> EN / FB / MR / AB / MY / JN / JL / AG / SP / OC / NV / DC.
>
> Tiene información detallada sobre las [abreviaturas de los meses](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Abreviaciones_en_fechas) en la Wikilengua.

En cuanto a la formación de las abreviaturas en general, el Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas da pistas interesantes en su artículo al respecto:

> [**abreviatura**](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=fKODyKTfZD6s0mX7bz)
>
> 3. Formación. La abreviatura ha de ser eficaz y, por eso, debe suprimir como mínimo dos letras de la palabra abreviada (mejor, tres, si la palabra es suficientemente larga, para poder ahorrar, al menos, dos caracteres, ya que una de las letras suprimidas es reemplazada por el punto de cierre); (...) Existen dos procedimientos para formar abreviaturas:
>
> a) Por truncamiento, suprimiendo letras o sílabas finales: cód. por código, art. por artículo. En este caso, la abreviatura nunca debe terminar en vocal: pról., y no pró. ni prólo., como abreviatura de prólogo. En el caso de las abreviaturas que corresponden a fórmulas fijas, se abrevian todas y cada una de las palabras que las integran, incluso artículos, preposiciones o conjunciones, reduciéndolos a la letra inicial: s. e. u o. por salvo error u omisión, q. e. p. d. por que en paz descanse.
>
> b) Por contracción, eliminando letras centrales y dejando solo las más representativas: dpto. o depto. por departamento, admr. por administrador. Entre las abreviaturas formadas por contracción están las que presentan la letra o letras finales voladas: n.o por número, af.mo por afectísimo.

Comment: íDios mío! Es un tema muy largo. Llevo siglos preparando mi CV por culpa de tales cosas que salen de improviso. jaja Muchas gracias por todo su esfuerzo. Útil información. Entonces, en un CV, ¿debo usar los códigos o las abreviaturas?

Comment: @مريممعاذ yo usaría los códigos, que son los que la gente conoce más.

Comment: Sí que son "poco comunes", sí...